# Is it permissible to read books in which the Prophet Muhammad(PBUH) is reviled/berated?

Tags: practical-islam, fiqh

I wonder if it's permissible to read a book in which Prophet Muhammad(PBUH) is reviled or depicted as someone bad, not directly but indirectly.

A well known example is *The Satanic Verses* by Salman Rushdie.

Answer (score 2):

It is okay to read these kind of books from a literary point of view. Before doing so one should be knowledgeable about his own religion and especially deeper understanding of Quran,do that information given does not cause you to be misguided.